# type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds workaround

Tags: java, generics

So is there any way to bypass the limitation so that the method `foo`of class DerivedA and DerivedB can have the signature i want?

```
class SuperA{
}

class SuperB{
}

interface InterfaceA{

}

interface InterfaceB<T>{
    <P extends T & InterfaceA> void foo(P param);
    //error:type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds
}

class DerivedA extends SuperA implements InterfaceB<SuperA>{

    @Override
    <P extends SuperA & InterfaceA> void foo(P param){
        //P should be some type extends SuperA and implements InterfaceA.
    }
}

class DerivedB extends SuperB implements InterfaceB<SuperB>{

    @Override
    <P extends SuperB & InterfaceA> void foo(P param){
        //P should be some type extends SuperB and implements InterfaceA.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can't be done as far I know.

You need to restrict `T` at creation and not later

```
interface InterfaceB<T extends InterfaceA>{
    <P extends T> void foo(P param);
}
```

Otherwise it would make no sense and would be impossible for the compiler to gurantee typesafety at compiletime, which is the purpose of generics in the first place.

Without restrictions `T` could be of type `Object` that does not implement your interface, but creation of a instance with generic parameter `Object` would not fail at Compile time, but calling it's method would not be Typesafe or would fail at compiletime, which makes little sense.

But this should not be a problem, you can put every Method that needs that signature `<P extends T & interface>` into another `InterfaceC`, because any Class can inherit any number of Interfaces this will solve your problem ultimately.

A working solution to your problem could look like that.

```
class SuperA implements InterfaceA{
}

class SuperB implements InterfaceA{
}

interface InterfaceA{

}

interface InterfaceB<T extends InterfaceA>{
    <P extends T> void foo(P param);
    //error:type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds
}

class DerivedA extends SuperA implements InterfaceB<SuperA>{
    @Override
    public <P extends SuperA> void foo(P param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class DerivedB extends SuperB implements InterfaceB<SuperB>{
    @Override
    public <P extends SuperB> void foo(P param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Or you can create subclasses of `SuperA` and `SuperB` that implement `InterfaceB`.

This is the only way to ensure compiletime Typesafety.

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds, but these workarounds can't guarantee everything `<P extends T & InterfaceA>` guarantees (future you might forget and mess things up a bit). Basically you can only chain on a previous type and only the first type can be whatever combination, but you can force another interface on the type only when declaring the interface.

You could add the child class that implements `InterfaceA+SuperA or InterfaceA+SuperB` inside `InterfaceB`

```
interface InterfaceB<T,T2 extends T>{ 
//T2 can only chain over T1
//but T1 can be anything, this case T1 extends Object, but it can extend any 1 Object + any multiple Interfaces 
    <T3 extends T2> void foo2(T3 param);
}

class DerivedA extends SuperA implements InterfaceB<SuperA,DerivedAWithInterfaceA>{ 
//this is kinda the only way to ensure that both SuperA+InterfaceA are used together 

    @Override
    public <T3 extends DerivedAWithInterfaceA> void foo2(T3 param) {}

}

class DerivedAWithInterfaceA extends DerivedA implements InterfaceA {
} 
//and now any SuperA+InterfaceA should extend this class instead of just SuperA
//idem class SuperB
```

Another approach would be but this one involves keeping an eye on the types declared for each child but it makes inheritance more stable:

```
class SuperA<T extends InterfaceA> implements InterfaceA{}

interface InterfaceA{}

interface InterfaceB<T,T2 extends T>{
    //T2 can only chain over T1
    //but T1 can be anything, this case T1 extends Object, but it can extend any 1 Object + any multiple Interfaces 
    <T3 extends T2> void foo2(T3 param);
    //T3 can chain or be like T and extend over something certain like T2 extends String&InterfaceA

    //void foo3(InterfaceB<? super InterfaceA,InterfaceA> example);
    //the only time you are allowed to use super is inside methods and only ? can use them(one the left, ie ? super T is allowed but T super ? not), but again this is only chaining
}

class DerivedA<T2 extends SuperA&InterfaceA> extends SuperA implements InterfaceB<SuperA,T2>{
//here you are making sure that T2 is always parent+InterfaceA and in children DerivedAChild extends DerivedA<T2 extends DerivedA&InterfaceA> is always this+InterfaceA
    @Override
    public <T3 extends T2> void foo2(T3 param) {
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.